# Polymer 3 - KeyframeEffect is not defined

Tags: polymer

Come on... I mean, how on earth do you expect people to start using Polymer if even a basic **paper-dropdown-menu** is NOT working out-of-the-box??

And then I had a look on Google, and there are a lot of people complaining about this bug:

> KeyframeEffect is not defined

And then using Bower I installed 'neon-animation' and 'web-animations-js'

> bower install --save PolymerElements/neon-animation
>
> bower install --save web-animations-js

And then, right after the import of 'webcomponents-loader.js', I added

> link rel="import" href="bower_components/web-animations-js/web-animations.html"

Or any of the other ' web-animations*.* '

And the thing is still **NOT** working!!!

I mean, guys, am I suppose to develop with Polymer and make *awesome* web app??

It's a bloody hell!

Come on...

Comment: Possible duplicate of [polymer 3.0 uncaught reference error on paper drop-down click](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52193786/polymer-3-0-uncaught-reference-error-on-paper-drop-down-click)

Comment: Bower is deprecated for npm. Here's a working [demo](https://glitch.com/edit/#!/twilight-grass) of `paper-dropdown-menu` with animations.